# Remove selected object in NSTableView from array

Tags: arrays, swift, macos

I have an array which contains some objects which are displayed in a NSTableView. I want to delete one of them within my control segment UI (- button).

My table is named deviceTable so I need to find out which row is selected.

```
deviceTable.selectedRow
```

I think I need some more code on this to get the selected row? Unsure with that... Now I need to find this object within the array (it's called *devices*) and delete the object. In Swift 3, that should be

```
ViewController.devices.remove
```

I need to give some information on this, because `RemoveAtIndex` has been replaced with `remove`. I don't know what to do there - any information on this?

Sorry for asking these questions that might be easy for your expertise guys, it's a problem for me here and I hope someone can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I definelty need some more sleep ._.

```
ViewController.devices.remove(at: deviceTable.selectedRow)
reloadData()
```